# Cloud 9 IDE and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, cloud9-ide

Has anyone successfully created a Ruby on Rails (2.3.8) with Ruby (1.8.7) on the Cloud 9 IDE?
I have tried several times, but the lack of documentation is a bit irritating, and every time I attempt to load the version of Ruby on Rails and Ruby that I need the whole workspace seems to break.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I can supply any additional information needed upon request.

Link to more information from post on Cloud9 IDE website: [Cloud9 IDE Support](http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/22023714-Ruby-1-8-7-Ruby-on-Rails-2-3-8-Issues)

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Solution:
You can not remove any gems currently installed, you can only install.
To generate the project the command needs to be:
$ rails _[VERSION]_ [PROJECT_NAME]
Then to run the server, you must be in the project folder and run script/server -b $IP -p $PORT.

Answer (score -2):

I used Cloud9 for around a year, and ended up migrating to [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) mainly because of issues like this. Koding gives you root access in your VM, so you can install and use whatever you like. None of these permission issues :)

Comment: That does not fix his ploblem, you simply marketing another app!